# How can I represent a sequence that involves repeating variables from a set?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Given a set s, e.g. s=[3,4,6,5], how can I represent a sequence **a** such that:

a(n) = 9 + n + s[n mod 4]

?

I am trying to do this on Wolfram Alpha but am having trouble. Also I don’t know the appropriate way to write this kind of thing for a monograph.

For clarity in my example:

a(1) = 9 + 1 + s[1] = 9+1+4 = 14

a(4) = 9 + 4 + s[0] = 9+4+3 = 16

etc.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply

$$a_n:=9+n+s_{n\bmod 4}.$$

Comment: a_n starts with 9.

Comment: @CommaToast: should I have guessed ?

Comment: Sorry. I phrased question wrong. But how do I do s_n on Wolfram Alpha?

Comment: @CommaToast: I don't know.